# Using Python Unittest to test results in an array

Tags: python, python-unittest

I've implemented a function which calculate annual mortgage repayment, and I want to test whether it generates the correct results.

I've put input mortgage values in an array, such as:

```
input_array([   50000.,   100000.,   150000., ...])
```

and the corresponding results in another array:

```
output_array([   3200.60,   6401.20,   9601.79, ...])
```

I'd like to take each of the elements in the input array as the input of my function and test the result is the same as output_array.

Is it possible to do it automatically rather than input the mortgage value and expected output in the `assertEqual` function manually?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options. The first, just compare whole arrays:

```
expected_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
output_list = calc_mortgage([10, 20, 30, 42])
self.assertEqual(expected_list, output_list)
```

The second, you can compare each element:

```
expected_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
output_list = calc_mortgage([10, 20, 30, 42])
for pair in zip(expected_list, output_list):
    self.assertEqual(pair[0], pair[1])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
assertListEqual(map(f, input_array), output_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

For numpy arrays, something like:

```
self.assertTrue(
    numpy.allclose(calc_mortgage([10, 20, 30, 42], [1, 2, 3, 4]),
    msg="calc_mortgage error"
)
```